# Snapping to position onDragEnd with motionValues using Framer Motion and React

Tags: reactjs, framerjs, framer-motion

I'm using framer motion to create a swipe interaction in my project. I'm trying to make it so that when the user is done dragging the child, it will 'snap' back into a set position.

I've seen from the docs that you can use a spring to animate a motion value: `const y = useSpring(x, { damping: 10 })`, but I guess I'm not doing it correctly? Heres my code:

```
export default function SwipeContainer(props) {
  const x = useMotionValue(0);
  const m = useSpring(x, { damping: 10 });

  const handleDragEnd = (evt) => {
    console.log(evt);
    m.set(200);
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.swipeContainer}>
      <motion.div
        style= {{ x, m }}
        className={styles.motionDiv}
        drag="x"
        onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
      >
        {props.children}
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

I'm expecting that when the dragEnd event happens, the child will animate to x:200, but thats not happening. Am I setting the value incorrectly, or perhaps its how I'm applying the motion values to the motion.div?

Answer (score 5):

I didn't experiment with `useSpring` yet, but you can get it to work with `useAnimation`.

Here's a CodeSandbox with a similar situation: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-bottom-sheet-fixed-m2vls.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This appears to be broken with v2 of Framer motion. Any idea on what need to change?

Comment: I had a quick look but didn't get it to work yet. It seems to me like there's a bug when you use dragging and `useAnimation` on the same component.

Comment: This problem is still persisting in v4. I opened an issue here https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/1170